# CSS Overflow: overlay. Is it deprecated? How can I replace it?

Tags: css

I have a legacy web app with non-standard css property value;

```
myClass{
    overflow: overlay;
}
```

I googled a bit, but did not found much about this property.
[This link](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/overflow.html) says that it works like `overflow:auto` for webkit browsers, but it is false.
[Simple sample to show the difference and existance of this value.](https://jsfiddle.net/11w3LLq1/) Checked in last chrome.

Is it deprecated now?
Is it a crutch for legacy browsers? (What browsers exactly?)
What is the semantic of this value?
Should I replace it?
How can I replace it?

Comment: I have no idea what it’s _supposed_ to look like (if it’s not supposed to look like `auto`), since my browser doesn’t support it as well.

Comment: @Xufox, check my fiddle in google chrome.

Comment: @ru_volt check this [discussion](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/92)

Comment: `overflow: overlay` is used internally by some Apple applications based on webkit, it displays the scrollbars, but in the "mini" version. It is something strictly related to OS X, you can safely replace it with `overflow: auto` if you are not targeting just OS X

Comment: @FezVrasta, it is clearer now, but it is not working like overlow: auto, check the fiddle in chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/11w3LLq1/. I have different behavior on windows

Comment: Ok, i read all links - and this value is kind of arcane knowledge. I will just replace it with overflow: auto very carrefully. Thanks all for help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Screenshot from mdn]
It is deprecated according to [Mozilla css docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

### Update 2023

`overflow: overlay` is now deprecated / unsupported by all major browsers, according to https://caniuse.com/?search=overflow%3A%20overlay.

---

###### You can look into [`scrollbar-gutter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter) if you are searching for some kind of alternative.

Comment: The value `overlay` was not only never a standard, as it was modified to behave like `auto`: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/236341/webkit

Answer (score 6):

There was/is an undocumented overlay option for overflow in webkit browsers. I don't suggest that you use until it's standardized.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32388

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to have the same effect that would not trigger reflow ever: using `visibility` property and nested blocks:

```
.scrollbox {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.scrollbox-content,
.scrollbox:hover,
.scrollbox:focus {
  visibility: visible;
}
```